# How to correctly sanitize mssql query that stores emails

Tags: php, sql-server

I have a query that goes to a mailbox and tries to save all emails in a table. It works in most cases but it fails when the email content value has double or single quote marks. How would I modify my code to correctly insert all queries?

```
    $num = imap_num_msg($imap);
    if($num > 0)
    {
        for($b = $num; $b > 0; $b--)
        {
            $body = $this->get_part($imap, $b, "TEXT/HTML");
            if($body == "")
            {
                $body = $this->get_part($imap, $b, "TEXT/PLAIN");
            }
            $header = imap_headerinfo($imap, $b);
            $subject = $header->subject;
            $fromaddress = $header->fromaddress;
            $body = str_replace("'", "''", $body);
            //$body = str_replace("\"", "\"\"", $body);
            $sql3 = "INSERT INTO [tbl_test] (content) 
                    VALUES ('".$body."')";
            $result3 = mssql_query($sql3, $dbh1);
        }
    }
```

Afterwords I get these errors:

Warning: mssql_query(): message: Unclosed quotation mark after the character string 'Please investigate why the below s....

Warning: mssql_query(): General SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server (severity 15) in /var/www/testing.php on line 38

Comment: You *never* want to compose a SQL command like this: using un-vetted data from outside your server's security control to build and then execute a SQL command.  This is how SQL Injection attacks work.  And while you might be able to solve your current "non-malicious" problems by data-cleansing, no amount of sanitation in the world can make it 100% safe against a malicious attack.  For that you need to use parametization (as in Jason Carter's answer), which also happens to solve your current problem.

Comment: Agreed, use a parameterized query / stored procedure, then you don't have to worry about single quotes and you don't have to worry about SQL injection (provided you don't just build dynamic SQL inside the procedure).

Comment: How do I use it on Ubuntu ?

Answer (score 3):

You want to be using parameters:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO test (email, body) VALUES (?,?);";
$arrParams[]="my@domain.com";
$arrParams[]="My email body has quotes\'s or double quotes \" in it.";
$resource=sqlsrv_query($conn, $query, $arrParams);
```

Source: [sqlsrv_query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296184%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: And as an added bonus, this also protects against SQL Injection attacks!

Comment: That was actually my first thought when I read the code, as a benefit, it also answers his question :)

Comment: Thank you very much, so if I go this way should I use functions like addslashes?

Comment: Also, how do I install this new extension for ubuntu? Im running PHP Version 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.5

Comment: No clue, might want to ask that question over at ServerFault.

Comment: Ok, so there is no way to use it with Linux. How about PDO instead? Would it work?