# How do I connect to mssql from ubuntu and php 5.3.10

Tags: php, sql-server, linux, ubuntu

I was having problems saving specific data using regular mssql_query as described here: [How to correctly sanitize mssql query that stores emails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15840642/how-to-correctly-sanitize-mssql-query-that-stores-emails)

As you can see, some people recommended sqlsrv driver however it's not available for linux. What would be the best way to use mssql on linux then?

Comment: use PDO (and prepared statements). don't use the 'raw' mssql_*() functions directly.

Answer (score 1):

At present, Microsoft provides support for Linux `Red Hat` distribution Driver only. And it should be on 64 bit OS. http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28160 
And also its not a OpenSource application, its very difficult get support on Enterprise edition too. I better prefer to go on with MYSQL Database

Answer (score 1):

As Marc B said, use PDO.  You'll also want to use the FreeTDS driver. You'll need to: `sudo apt-get install tdsodbc unixodbc php5-odbc`.

You can see further configuration [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13066716/freetds-not-using-its-config/13069820#13069820).